# C++ compile-type resource owner assertion

Tags: c++, resources, compile-time, ownership

```
class Resource;

class Device
{
    ...
public:
    Resource createResource();

    bindResource(const Resource&);
};

int main()
{
    Device dev;
    Device oops;

    auto res = dev.createResource();

    dev.bindResource(res); // Okay; dev created this resource

    oops.bindResource(res); // Error: oops did not create this resource
}

Program does not compile
```

Can this be done completely at compile-time with no runtime overhead and similar syntax?
Example, device is an abstraction of a Direct3D renderer; we can't share some resources, should be a compile time error if we try.

Comment: No, compiler can't track where the resource is being used, so you have to do it run-time.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround, which uses `__COUNTER__` macro. Though it is not provided by the standard, MSVC and GCC support it. This macro relates to an integer value, which is incremented every time you use this macro in a translation unit. So, the implementation is the following:

```
// Device.h
#define DEVICE Device<__COUNTER__>

template<int N>
class Device
{
public:
    class Resource{};
    Resource createResource() { return Resource(); }
    void bindResource(const Resource&) {}
};
```

As you can see, the `Resource` class is now declared inside a `Device` class. All instances of `Device` class should be declared using the `DEVICE` macro. Now, `dev` and `oops` instanses are instantiated as objects of different types. `dev` is `Device<0>` and `oops` is `Device<1>`. And, respectively, `res` is now `Device<0>::Resource`, and oops can't bind it.

This approach, however, has the following drawbacks (at least):
1) Passing Devices as function arguments is a problem. To guarantee the compile-time checking, all functions that deal with Devices should also be templates. It may lead to a significant code bloating.
2) If you declare an array of DEVICE type (for example, DEVICE devices[10]), all devices will be of the same type, and, thus, will be able to bind the resources of each other.
3) **__COUNTER__** macro  provides unique values only through the single translation unit. If you declare `dev` at the beginning of one translation unit and `oops` at the beginning of the second translation unit, their types will be equal, and `oops` will be able to bind the `dev`'s resources.
4) **__COUNTER__** is not provided by the standard.

After all, I don't recommend you to use this workaround, it may be useful only for educational purposes :)

Comment: Ah, interesting, the COUNTER macro is new to me. I had tried templating by an int ID but as you raised, code is replicated for each new ID in that case. Tried some inheritance tricks and it gets really confusing.

Comment: I hate how lots of APIs have complications like this that theoretically could be compile-time checked as they are logical errors but with the languages we have it just doesn't happen.

Comment: Oh, and sorry I can't vote you up; I haven't the reputation required.